# Is there any relationship between the $\mathrm{Ann} (M) $ and $\mathrm{Ann} (m_0) $ (other than that $\mathrm{Ann}(M)\subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(m_0) $)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with identity with a 2 sided ideal $I$ and a left ideal $L$ such that $I\subseteq L$. Must there exist a left $R$-module $M$ and an element $m_0$ of $M $ such that $\mathrm{Ann}(m_0)=L,\mathrm{Ann}(M)=I$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, take $M=R/I\oplus R/L$ and $m_0=(0,1)$.

Comment: Agree that your example answers my question. I have a comment though: how can this work even if I were just a left ideal? Annhilator of a module must be 2 sided

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I'm too used to thinking about commutative rings...